# What is the difference between an object being immutable vs the reference to the object being immutable?

Tags: java

I am confused over this because having a final field `b` of `type B` inside an `Object A` just ensures that the field  `b` can't be instantiated again but the state of `A` can be still be changed by manipulating `b` internally or externally, so how does final serve the purpose immutablity here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` helps to implement an immutable object. The immutable object must ensure that any objects it owns are themselves immutable or at least not publicly mutable.

There is no royal path to immutability in Java (or otherwise, I may add).

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer to you last question is: it doesn't.

Unless there is no way to mutate the state of 'b', final will gain you nothing with respect to the mutability of 'a'.

These are orthogonal concepts, however using "final" in all possible places will help you achieve object immutability, although it is not necessary and you can do without.

Answer (score 1):

Making the field `final` provides a compile-time check that A is not modifying the *reference* to B.

Although this is not sufficient to guarantee the immutability of A, it is helpful.

*Defensive copies* can prevent external modification of the mutable object that b references. Defensive copies can be made both for objects received by an A constructor, and for objects returned by A accessors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think the difference essentially is so that using the `final` keyword merely assures you as the programmer that a variable will refer to the same object at all times through out the execution. There is however nothing preventing the object itself to change in some way.

Consider the following pseudocode: `final Car c = new BMW(Color.Green, new Milage(0));`

you cannot assign `c` to an Audi, or a Ford later on in the code, but there is no limit in "using" your BMW so that it's milage increases over the course of your program.

Answer (score 0):

object being immutable - means the data or vales of the variables in that object can't be changed once set.

reference being immutable - means the variable which is pointing to that object is a final variable.